# Добавить класс дочернему элементу текущего

Tags: jquery

Нужно сделать чтобы при наведении на ._s-row показывал заголовок.
Делаю так:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('._s-row').hover(
    function() {
      jQuery(this).find('._s-img-wrap').addClass('hover')
    },
    function() {
      jQuery(this).find('._s-img-wrap').removeClass('hover')
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но класс добавляется всем элементам, а нужно чтобы только тому на который наведен курсор. Как это исправить?

Comment: У вас нет класса _s-img-wrap

Comment: У Вас всё верно, нужно лишь искать правильный класс (вместо `_s-img-wrap` искать `_s-title-wrap`).

Comment: @Other, и правда все работает) не почистил кэш движка

Answer (score 1):

Из того, что есть,  ты вроде бы этого хотел. Хотя, чем тебе `css`-ий `hover` не угодил, не совсем понятно....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('._s-row').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('._s-title-wrap').toggleClass('hover')
  });
});
```

```css
._s-title-wrap.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="_s-row">
  <img src="" />
  <div class="_s-title-wrap">
    <h2>Заголовок3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```